# LEFT JOIN in MS Access with multiple criterion and without duplicates

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

May I ask for your help for the below task using SQL left join statement in Microsoft Access? Thank you!

Objective (Please also refer to the below tables):

1. The number of records in the result table (A + B) should be identical to that of table A
2. The valueB1 mapped from table B to table A should be the closest value smaller than valueA1 of the corresponding id in table A
3. If all of the valueB1 for the same ID in table B are greater than the valueA1 of the corresponding id in table A, then use the lowest valueB1 in table B

Table A (Input)

```
Id  ValueA1
A   10
B   20
C   30
```

Table B (Configuration table)

```
id  ValueB1
A   20
A   30
A   40
B   15
B   25
B   35
C   18
C   28
C   38
```

Table A + B (Expected result)

```
id  ValueA1 ValueB1
A   10      20
B   20      15
C   30      28
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working sample in MS SQL Server:

```
Select 'A' as Id, 10 as ValueA1 into #A
Insert into #A (Id,ValueA1 ) VALUES ('B', 20), ('C', 30)

Select 'A' as Id, 20 as ValueB1 into #B
Insert into #B (Id,ValueB1 ) VALUES ('A', 30), ('A', 40)
Insert into #B (Id,ValueB1 ) VALUES ('B', 15), ('B', 25), ('B', 35)
Insert into #B (Id,ValueB1 ) VALUES ('C', 18), ('C', 28), ('C', 38)

SELECT #A.Id, #A.ValueA1, coalesce(Max(Minors.ValueB1), Min(Majors.ValueB1))
FROM #A 
      LEFT JOIN (
                  SELECT #A.Id, #A.ValueA1, Max(#B.ValueB1) ValueB1   
                    FROM #A LEFT JOIN #B ON #A.Id = #B.Id   
                   WHERE #B.ValueB1 < #A.ValueA1 GROUP BY #A.Id, #A.ValueA1
                 ) Minors ON Minors.Id = #A.Id
      LEFT JOIN (
                   SELECT #A.Id, #A.ValueA1, Min(#B.ValueB1) ValueB1  
                     FROM #A LEFT JOIN #B ON #A.Id = #B.Id   
                    WHERE #B.ValueB1 >= #A.ValueA1 GROUP BY #A.Id, #A.ValueA1
                 ) Majors ON Majors.Id = #A.Id
GROUP BY #A.Id, #A.ValueA1 

DROP TABLE #A
DROP TABLE #B
```

I think that with small changes you can adapt this to MS Access, for example the coalesce function that keep the first not-null element can be replaced with NZ(field1, field2)

Here is Access compatible version:

```
SELECT TableA.Id, TableA.ValueA1, Nz(Max(Minors.ValueB1),Min(Majors.ValueB1)) 
AS ValueB1
FROM 
   (SELECT TableA.Id, TableA.ValueA1, Max(TableB.ValueB1) AS ValueB1
    FROM TableA LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.Id = TableB.Id
    WHERE TableB.ValueB1 < TableA.ValueA1
    GROUP BY TableA.Id, TableA.ValueA1
   ) AS Minors 
RIGHT JOIN 
   (
     (SELECT TableA.Id, TableA.ValueA1, Min(TableB.ValueB1) AS ValueB1
      FROM TableA LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.Id = TableB.Id
      WHERE TableB.ValueB1 >= TableA.ValueA1
      GROUP BY TableA.Id, TableA.ValueA1
     ) AS Majors 
     RIGHT JOIN TableA ON Majors.ValueA1 = TableA.ValueA1
   ) 
ON Minors.ValueA1 = TableA.ValueA1
GROUP BY TableA.Id, TableA.ValueA1;
```

Comment: @June7 Thank you very much for your kind assistance. It works perfectly and what I just needed to do is to replace the variables with the actual variables in my Access DB. Really appreciate!

Comment: @ Christian L. : I would also like to thank Christian L. for your initial answer. It saves my effort in finding solution from the other resources! Really appreciate!

Comment: you are welcome; it was on purpose, I thought that a first step would get nearer the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Only SQL non-VBA solution I can immediately see uses domain aggregate functions.

```
SELECT TableA.ID, TableA.ValueA1, Nz(DMax("ValueB1","TableB","ID='" & [ID] & "' 
        AND ValueB1<" & [ValueA1]),DMin("ValueB1","TableB","ID='" & [ID] & "'")) AS ValueB1
        FROM TableA;
```

If that performs slowly with very large dataset, VBA custom function might be better.